# missing pages from Behavior>Site Content>All Pages

Tags: google-analytics

I have a few pages that are not showing up under Behavior>Site Content>All Pages or Behavior>Site Content>Landing Pages.  I know the pages are being visited because Behavior>Events>Pages shows my GA tags for these pages.

I thought it was just a lag, but some of the Events I track for these pages are over a week old.

Any suggestions as to why these pages are missing from Behavior>Site Content>All Pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a **pageview hit is not being sent** to Google Analytics on the pages that are missing from All Pages report. Just event hits are sent.

To check this navigate to one of the pages with missing tracking and use one of the browser plugins to look for the pageview hit:

- [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en)
- [WASP.inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/waspinspector-analytics-s/niaoghengfohplclhbjnjheodgkejpih?hl=en)

You can also use the Realtime report in Google Analytics whether you see your visit there.

*Note: Make sure you are not blocking GA in your browser when doing the check.*

[image: Google Analytics - Realtime]

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up having some Javascript that was interfering with analytics.js loading.